# Why does the RST packet not need the TIME_WAIT state?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, time-wait

I know that `TIME_WAIT` is to prevent delayed segments from one connection being misinterpreted as being part of a subsequent connection. Any segments that arrive whilst a connection is in the TIME_WAIT wait state are discarded.

In my experiment, I can't see `TIME_WAIT` when a client sends an RST packet  instead of a FIN packet. Why?

**Server**

```
while (1) {
    int len = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
    fd = accept(sfd, &remote, &len);

    read(fd, buf, sizeof(buf));

    strcpy(buf, "Hello Client");
    write(fd, buf, strlen(buf));

    close(fd);
}
```

**Client**

```
res = connect(sfd, result->ai_addr, result->ai_addrlen);

strcpy(buf, "Hello Server!");
write(sfd, buf, strlen(buf));

close(sfd);
```

**NOTE:** The client sends RST instead of FIN because it does not read buffered data already sent by the server before closing the socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you `close(2)` a connection with pending of receiving data, the connection is broken, as you are not reading all the pending data (that can be in the buffer, acknowledged, unacknowledged or simply in transit)  you are breaking the state machine and this is what provokes a `RST` (which is sent from your host to the other end, on response to any data segment that arrives to this side of the connection).  If, as suggested, you read the RFC document, the connection is in an error state and will reply with a `RST` frame to every packet it receives... it is not anymore in the `TIME_WAIT` state.

Calling `close(2)` before reading the `EOF` (an unblocking read of 0 bytes, when you have already received a `FIN` from the other end) condition **is a protocol error**, as the receiving side (you) is lossing the remaining data in transit to your side.  You have a system call `shutdown(2)` for the purpose of signalling your intention of not writing more data (half closing your sending side), and allow to wait for the remaining data to come, and it forces your side to send a `FIN` to the other end and put the connection in the `FIN_WAIT1` state (waiting for the `ACK` of your `FIN` and/or `FIN&ACK` from the other side)

## NOTE

`TIME_WAIT` state is a state to ensure that any `in-transit` packet has enough time to arrive at destination and be correctly processed.  As the connection has failed with both ends **unsynchronized**, there's no sense on waiting for any packet to arrive, as they **cannot be correctly processed**.  No packet is sent in response to a `RST` and connection normally goes to the `CLOSED` state.

RFC-793 specifically says:

**Sec 3.4 Establishing a connection**

[...]

```
Reset Processing

In all states except SYN-SENT, all reset (RST) segments are validated
by checking their SEQ-fields.  A reset is valid if its sequence number
is in the window.  In the SYN-SENT state (a RST received in response
to an initial SYN), the RST is acceptable if the ACK field
acknowledges the SYN.

The receiver of a RST first validates it, then changes state.  If the
receiver was in the LISTEN state, it ignores it.  If the receiver was
in SYN-RECEIVED state and had previously been in the LISTEN state,
then the receiver returns to the LISTEN state, otherwise the receiver
aborts the connection and goes to the CLOSED state.  If the receiver
was in any other state, it aborts the connection and advises the user
and goes to the CLOSED state.
```

So, as you can read... no `TIME_WAIT` state for `RST` in any case.

Comment: why `RST` needn't `TIME_WAIT` state ? `RST` packet can also be delayed in the network. So, I think `TIME_WAIT` is nessary.

Comment: @Pengcheng Your question asks why arrival of RST doesn't put a port into TIME_WAIT state. Your comment here refers to an RST packet that is itself delayed, i.e. that arrives *during* the TIME_WAIT state. It is a completely different condition and a completely different question. An RST that arrives during TIME_WAIT will abort it. .

Comment: `RST` packet can be delayed, even lost in the network.  Nobody waits for a `RST` packet.  There's no sense to wait for a `RST` packet. `RST` packets are sent to the other side to inform of the unsynchronized state between two parties. You don't have to wait for them.

Comment: Even more... if **both implementations are correct**, the only way to provoque a `RST` is the one mentioned above (full closing a connection when data is in transit to here ---and it's an implementation dependency as it is not protocol related) or somebody injecting *in order* packets to force unsynchronized states at both ends.  Even in that case, `TIME_WAIT` is not there to cope with `RST` packets.

Comment: @EJP If RST does not need **TIME_WAIT**, data error may happen in a  fast speed network due to delayed **RST** packet. So, I think when server receives a **RST** packet, it should turn to **TIME_WAIT**.

Comment: @Pengcheng, nope.... when you receive a `RST` packet you don't receive any other `RST`packet from the other end... you can loose it, but not receive it delayed.... You only receive one... and if you swith to `TIME_WAIT` due of a `RST` you'll not receive more `RST` packets (nor `FIN`, nor `ACK` with a sequence number past the one received in the connection)  More, if you have received a `RST` because the injection of a data segment from a third party, you'll have acknowledge the incorrect data (the injected one) to the other end and given it for valid.

Comment: @Luis Colorado, I remember you said 'RST packet can be delayed'. Why not received it delayed? Why only receive one ?

Comment: You can receive it delayed... but you are only going to receive one... so how can you detect at receiver it is delayed? you cannot.  `RST` is only an indication of that the other end is abandoning the connection (it goes to the closed state)  If you insist in sending more data, you'll receive (as part of the `LISTEN` part of the protocol) another `RST`, and so until you actually understand the connection has been broken and no chance of repairing it.

Comment: We can be debating during decades on this.  But TCP is alive for almost 35 years and nobody has said `RST` needs to switch to `TIME_WAIT` state (there's no connection state, as both ends are unsynchronized, so I think the `CLOSED` state is the proper one to go to)   If you don't agree, write IETF for an amendment in RFC-793 and not try to convince me of something that is not only useless, but incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is stating that there is no such connection and its effect is to terminate it without prejudice.

To put it another way, because RFC 793 explicitly says that on `RST` reception no response is to be sent and you must go into the `CLOSED` state (except in some cases related to connection establishment in which case you go to the `LISTEN` state again).

Comment: By the way, the `RST`  is **indeed part of the connection**, it has to comply with the serial sequence number of the point of break in the connection, and the acknowledge received up to this moment.  If it doesn't fail in the window, it must be ignored, as fake. Indeed the reason to use cryptographically secure initial sequence numbers is to avoid DOS attacks consisting in using predictable sequence numbers to send RST segments and break connections.